# MySQL permission denied error even after setting security context for SELinux on VM

Tags: centos, mysql, selinux

I have MySQL installed on CentOS (detail versions given below). My OS is a VM machine and not a physical machine, the directory `/data/mysql` is a local disk (virtual). I suspect I might need to do some extra steps in a virtualized environment. This [link has some information on SELinux & virtualization](http://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Security_for_virtualization-SELinux_considerations.html) but not sure how to include it for MySQL.

MySQL works fine with the data directory in `/var/lib/mysql` but the moment I move it to another directory on different disk it stops working. Whereas different directory on the same disk works. If I disable SELinux, MySQL works with different disk. SELinux is restricting different drive. I tried the solution given in the following two links

- [SELinux and MySQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/selinux_and_mysql)
- [Re: Moved datadir and now get: ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,520100,520469#msg-520469)

In particular the following two commands:

```
$ semanage fcontext --add --type mysqld_db_t '/data/mysql(/.*)?'
$ restorecon -r /data/mysql
```

When I run:

```
$ ls -dZ /data/mysql
```

I get the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x. mysql mysql unconfined_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:SystemLow
```

Still I keep getting:

> /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/data/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

Is there anything else I need to do?

- MySQL : mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.14, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
- OS : CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

Comment: /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts file doesn't have entry for path. I am pretty new to SELinux. Not sure what to edit there.

Comment: I checked /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local and there were several entries which were added during trying out different command. I removed everything  using semanage fcontext -D and re-ran semanage fcontext --add --type mysqld_db_t '/data/mysql(/.*)?' and it worked.

Comment: I also needed to change the container of that folder to var_lib_t type. Not sure why this matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything directly wrong with what you're doing in terms of the commands you're running or how you're approaching the addition of `/data/mysql` with respect to SELinux.

Just to make sure things are working properly I would check if present and/or manually add this line to `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local`.

```
/data/mysql(/.*)?   system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0
```

When I repeated your steps above I had that line added to my `file_contexts.local` file as expected.

I would double check your steps you're following against the steps discussed here in this Redhat specific document titled: [10.4.1. MySQL Changing Database Location](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-MySQL-Configuration_Examples.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info about file_contexts.local. My file_contexts.local had lot of interfering entries. I cleaned all of them using semanage fcontext -D and readded semanage fcontext --add --type mysqld_db_t '/data/mysql(/.*)?'

Comment: @user2619299 - excellent, glad this resolved your problem. Thanks for the Q.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can occur without SELinux and AppArmor on Debian 9 and other systemd-based distros, when the MySQL datadir is moved anywhere under /home.

The reason for this is the systemd service file (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service) contains the setting:  **ProtectHome=true** .  This setting will prevent MySQL from writing to any folder under /home  and thus it will throw ErrNo 13: Permission Denied errors on startup.

The fix is to either move the data dir out of /home, or otherwise to turn off this security feature in the systemd service file:

1: **sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service /etc/systemd/system/**  # make a local override of the service file

2: Edit **/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service** and change *ProtectHome* to be false (**ProtectHome=false**). Save the file

3: **sudo systemd daemon-reload** # refresh the systemd services so it sees your override file

4: **sudo systemctl start mysql** # and it should finally start

Comment: I've been searching for why my table-level `DATA DIRECTORY` specification wouldn't work. Turns out it only happens when using a directory in `/home`, which led me to this answer. Thank you!

Comment: In the hopes it helps someone else out there, these are the specific error messages I was receiving: `2020-10-06  1:48:28 14 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2020-10-06  1:48:28 14 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.`

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to OS privilages issue. Please run following commands.

```
semanage fcontext -a -e /var/lib/mysql /opt/mysql
restorecon -R -v /opt/mysql
```